# Android Studio Auto Import without pressing shortcuts

Tags: android, android-studio

I have just migrated from eclipse to android studio and i am used to not having to explicitly press anything for importing a class, unless ovcourse there is a conflict or more then one candidates, unfortounately its not the same in my android studio by default, how do i set Android Studio to auto import without any special explicit action by me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable "Auto import"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> Code Style -> Java -> Imports

Android Studio is a fork of IntelliJ IDEA, if you have any problem with it, google for intellij instead of Android studio, they have very good documentation.

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/general-guidelines.html

Comment: I have been there and didnt find anything that allows AS to auto import, can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

```
## For Windows Users only ##
Navigate to -
               Files > Settings > Editor > General > Auto Import

Check on -
            1] Show import popup. ✓
            2] Add unambiguous imports on the fly. ✓
            3] Optimize imports on the fly. ✓
            4] Auto import in completion. ✓

Then you are set.
```